# Eliminate Carriage Return from a table in R

Tags: r, carriage-return

Need advise how to get rid of the CR (carriage returns) when reading in as well as writing out a table in R.

For example, when opened my file in Notepad ++ I see "CRLF" in the end of each row:

```
ID_1 ID_2 age bmi A1 B2 'CRLF'
124 2532 40 33 0.444 0.333 'CRLF'
126 2103 41 38 0.422 0.137 'CRLF'
```

I wanted to get rid of the CR (LF is okay):

```
ID_1 ID_2 age bmi A1 B2 'LF'
124 2532 40 33 0.444 0.333 'LF'
126 2103 41 38 0.422 0.137 'LF'
```

Comment: why would help, it is unix, windows thing and you may not want to explicitly change. or do you.

Comment: I could do it in Unix with:   tr -d '\r' < infile > outfile      but I want to do it in R though

Comment: The internal representation in R has neither `<cr>` nor `<lf>` when read from disk files with `read.table` It is unclear what problem you are trying to solve. The default for eol in `write.table` is just `"\n"` which is gererally thought to be a `<cr>`. Are you trying to write from an R object to a text file with something other than the standard for your unstated OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows which appears to be your OS, open the file in "binary" mode  to circumvent the usual OS-dependent way of encoding end-of-line.

```
mydf <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10) )
dest <- file("out.csv", open="wb")
write.table(mydf, file=dest, quote=FALSE, sep=" ", eol="\n")
close(f)
```

Comment: Given no one has asked this question in the past 4.5 years, I'm probably missing something, but should the last line of your code be `close(dest)`? What is `f`?

Comment: Damn good question. I don’t have a working Win-box at the moment but would guess those should be ‘close(dest)’.